# Android O Geofence Trigger Delay

Tags: android, android-geofence, android-8.0-oreo

I have a navigation app that used geofences([Creating and Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)).

Google says ([Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-location-limits.html#apis)):

> The average responsiveness for a geofencing event is every couple of
>   minutes or so.

On previous Android versions was no delay. But on Android O, the app shows a delay of ~4-5 minutes after leaving a geofence(approximately 50% of cases). Tested on ODP2

Has anybody faced a similar problem?

Comment: This is a worry if it's true. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I'm seeing ~5 minute delays also when testing on a Pixel 2 running 8.1.0, build number OPM2.171026.006.C1.

Comment: facing the same issue,geofence not tracking accurate enter and exit,it takes at-least 3 to 5 min to call enter for particular created fence and same for exit..any solution to get more accuracy i am also updating my gps coordinates as my geofence code return in a service class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google added new paragraph to [Create and monitor geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) doc

> Alerts can be late. The geofence service doesn't continuously query for location, so expect some latency when receiving alerts. Usually the latency is less than 2 minutes, even less when the device has been moving. If Background Location Limits are in effect, the latency is about 2-3 minutes on average. If the device has been stationary for a significant period of time, the latency may increase (up to 6 minutes).